# how to break in ollydbg debugger?

Tags: debugging, ollydbg

i'm really new to debugging, and debugging is not my strong point so just so i'm not confusing anyone, i'm not asking how to set a `breakpoint` in a program using ollydbg, but the `break` feature, somewhat similar to the `break` that is available in visual c++ debugger when debugging a program there, is this available at all in ollydbg?

if it is then what do i do it use it? or if it's not then is there anything else that i can do to similate a `break` in a program using the ollydbg WIN32 debugger?

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is the "Break all" feature of the Visual Studio debugger, which suspends all threads and sets the cursor to the currently executing source line (or one of them, at least, you can use the threads tab to change threads)...
... then this is analagous to the OllyDbg pause function, which again suspends all threads and sets the cursor to the actively executing instruction.

To change between threads you can simply open the threads view (alt+t) and press enter on the required thread. This will take you to the EIP for that thread.